# How to get time in micro seconds with out refresh in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get time without refresh in php,
my current code is

```
$format = 'DATE_W3C';
$time =time();
```

but $time only get updated when I refresh page, even if I call it at several places, I get same time

Comment: what you are trying to accomplish? using javascript and time there is much preferable, as u mentioned page without referesh, means you need time on client. So use javascript

Comment: i am trying to update time every time in my ajax success function

Answer (score 1):

`microtime` is the name of the function use `microtime()` to get a string and `microtime(true)` to get a float.

Comment: microtime() even gives same value

Comment: That sounds like a caching issue. in your ajax request try appending a random query value. So if you had `foo.php` do `foo.php + "?rand=" + Math.random()`

Answer (score -1):

this will get the microtime with out refreshing the page

if you want to update the time automatically for every 5 seconds then add this in your code

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('time.php'), function(data) {
            $("#time").html(data);
        }); 
});
</script>
<div id="time">
</div>
```

in **time.php**

```
<?php
echo microtime(true);
?>
```